# Filters: client and server side redirecting

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

That's my filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws java.io.IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    String currentURL = request.getRequestURI();
    MaintenanceService maintenanceMode = new MaintenanceService();

    if (maintenanceMode.getMaintenanceMode())
    {
        String urlNew = currentURL.concat("maintenance.jsp");
        response.sendRedirect(urlNew);

    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

"under" maintenanceMode.getMaintenanceMode(), I have variable getter:

```
boolean maintenanceMode = Boolean.getBoolean("maintenance");
```

With *forward* (server-side redirect) it works fine, when I'm trying client-side redirect:

```
response.sendRedirect(urlNew);
```

I got an infinite occurrences maintenance.jsp concatenating:

```
http://localhost:8080/maintenance.jspmaintenance.jspmaintenance.jspmaintenance.jspmaintenance.jsp
```

why it's not redirecting onto one occurrence, like with server-side redirect:

```
http://localhost:8080/maintenance.jsp
```

Web.xml filter mapping:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>maintenanceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Can please post us you filter mapping in web.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are redirecting for all URLS including `maintenance.jsp`. And it is resulting in an infinite redirection.

Modified the redirection condition to redirect only if the current url is not `maintenance.jsp`.

**Below is how the code looks after my change:**

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,ServletResponse servletResponse,
      FilterChain filterChain)
    throws java.io.IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException
{
   HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
   HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
   String currentURL = request.getRequestURI();
   MaintenanceService maintenanceMode = new MaintenanceService();
   if (!currentURL.equals("/maintenance.jsp") 
            && maintenanceMode.getMaintenanceMode())
   {
    String urlNew = currentURL.concat("maintenance.jsp");
    response.sendRedirect(urlNew);
   }
   filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

I did not understand why are you doing `String urlNew = currentURL.concat("maintenance.jsp");`
 for every url. Do you have `maintenance.jsp` page relative to every url. I think you should be having a single `/maintenance.jsp` page. And in such case it is have to redirect always to `response.sendRedirect(/maintenance.jsp)` irrespective of page you are accessing.

Comment: yes, I have one page for maintenance: if (!currentURL.equals("/maintenance.jsp") && maintenanceMode.getMaintenanceMode())
        {
            response.sendRedirect("/maintenance.jsp");
        }

Comment: yes, that's why I've approved your answer :) Thank you, anyway !

Answer (score 0):

```
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>maintenanceFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

In filter mapping your all requests (they are new requests as they are being redirected )are eligible for this `filter` this is the reason why your filter is being called on every request for infinite times .

One way is you can call this filter for specific `url-pattern`

Comment: you mean for dirty coding smth like:<url-pattern>localhost:8080/*</url-pattern> ? Besides i'm thinking about migrating to spring bean from web.xml

Comment: what do you mean by dirty coding?